# MySQL: How can I change a field that has a foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables that are linked by a foreign key constraint. I would like to change an ID field but the following code fails due to the foreign key constraint:

```
UPDATE A SET id = 1479 WHERE id = 2103;
UPDATE B SET Aid = 1479 WHERE Aid = 2103;
```

I know I can set up `ON CASCADE` to do this automatically, but how can I do it on a case-by-case basis like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [disabling foreign key checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and by running everything within a transaction.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
UPDATE A SET id = 1479 WHERE id = 2103;
UPDATE B SET Aid = 1479 WHERE Aid = 2103;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I guess I better go read up on transactions then...never had a need to use them.

Comment: You don't need the transaction, but the connection could drop between the two update statements. Then you will have a hard time 'rebuilding' your keys ;)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

before your update queries.